# Extract Paragraph Data without any tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have written a **scraper** that **scrapes** off data from a website but unfortunately the data on website is inconsistent. sometimes the paragraph is written using `<p>` tags and sometimes not. (Code Snippet given below)
Is there any dynamic way of knowing that?

**Part of Code that Generates Error**

```
main_content = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "story-detail"})
content = ""
for div in main_content:
    links = div.findAll('p')
    for a in links:
        a = str(a).strip('<p>')
        a = str(a).strip('/>')
        a = str(a).strip('<')
        a = str(a).strip('<br>')
        content = content + a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the text via `text` attribute. In that case you don't need to worry about underlying structure.

Example:

```
>>> soup = Soup(first, 'html.parser')
>>> soup
<div class="story-detail">test</div>

>>> soup.find('div').text
'test'
>>> soup = Soup(second, 'html.parser')
>>> soup
<div class="story-detail">another <p>test</p></div>

>>> soup.find('div').text
'another test'
```

Comment: This is great but i want the text in a particular class not from all the divs

Comment: @AsadMahmood it's just an example. You can still query by class or other properties. The point is getting all underlying text no matter what elements are there.

Answer (score 0):

if what you are trying to accomplish is to strip all the `<p>` and `</p>` tags from your text I would use regular expressions as follows:

```
main_content = ["a div without p tags", "<p>a div with p tags</p>"]

import re

for i in range(0,len(main_content)):
   main_content[i] = re.sub("<p>|</p>","",main_content[i])
```

Comment: but what if the data text has no <p> tags. like <div class="something"> here is a text without tags</div>

Comment: what would you need to do in that case ? my example would just return: <div class="something"> here is a text without tags</div>